# How does the dialog for W11 work?

Tags: terminal, user-input, input-methods

If I edit a file outside of a Vim session, then go back to the Vim session, I get this nice message:

```
W11: Warning: File "~/.vimrc" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

How does it work?

I know that

- `inputlist({textlist})` prompts the user to type numbers corresponding to the indices of the alternatives
- `input({prompt} [, {text} [, {completion}]])` prompts the user to type "extended" text

Whereas the message prompt I pasted above just requires the user to hit <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd>.

How do I replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:h confirm()`.

```
" prefer console dialogs in GVim too
"set guioptions+=c

let text =<< trim END
    W11: Warning: File "~/.vimrc" has changed since editing started
    See ":help W11" for more info.
END
echo confirm(join(text, "\n"), "&OK\n&Load File", 1, "Warning")
```